# Differentiablity of the complex function $f(\bar{z})$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a complex valued function which is differentiable at $z_{0}$ and $\bar z_{0}$. How to decide when the function $f(\bar{z})$ is differentiable at $z_{0}?$ I tried as below
$$ \lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}\frac{f(\bar{z})-f(\bar{z_{0}})}{z-z_{0}}= \lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}\frac{f(\bar{z})-f(\bar{z_{0}})}{\bar z-\bar z_{0}}\frac{\bar{z}-\bar{z_{0}}}{z-z_{0}}$$ The right side limit is a product, of which one limit $\frac{\bar{z}-\bar{z_{0}}}{z-z_{0}}$ does not exist. I conclude one thing that if $f'(\bar z_{0})$ exist then it must equal to zero. Am i right? Can i conclude that if $f$ is non constant and analytic then $f(\bar z)$ is nowhere analytic? Please help me. When the function $f(\bar z)$ is differentiable? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. If $g(z):=f\bigl(\bar z\bigr)$, and $f: \> z\mapsto f(z)$ happens to be complex differentiable at $\bar z_0$ then
$$g(z_0+Z)-g(z_0)=f\bigl(\bar z_0+\bar Z\bigr)-f\bigl(\bar z_0\bigr)=f'\bigl(\bar z_0\bigr)\>\bar Z +o\bigl(|Z|\bigr)\qquad(Z\to0)\ .$$
The main part of the right hand side is not complex linear in the variable $Z$ unless $f'(\bar z_0)=0$. It follows that $g$ cannot be analytic (i.e., complex differentiable at all points $z_0$ of an open set $\Omega\subset{\mathbb C}$) unless $f'(\bar z_0)\equiv0$ in $\Omega$.